# how to order the nested array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I would like to know how to filter and get the object based on order using javascript

I have a `obj` as shown below and should filter based on order and concat.

```
`obj` with `no error key && amt > min` should display at the top in sorted manner by amt.
`obj` with `amt<min` should display next 
`obj` with `error` should display last
```

```
var output = orderData(obj);
function orderData(obj){
  var minData = obj.filter(e=>e.amt<e.min);
  var errData = obj.filter(e=>e.hasOwnProperty("error"));
  var validData = obj.filter(e=>!e.hasOwnProperty("min") && !e.hasOwnProperty("error"));
  var result = validData.concat(errData).concat(minData);
return result;
}

var obj =[{
 "id": "trans",
 "amt": 1000
},{
 "id": "fund",
 "amt": 500
},{
  "id": "inst",
  "amt": 2000,
  "error": "invalid"
},{
  "id": "wf",
  "amt": 600,
  "min":  2000
},{
  "id": "sf",
  "amt": 500,
  "min": "250"
}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
 "id": "fund",
 "amt": 500
},{
  "id": "sf",
  "amt": 500,
  "min": "250"
},{
 "id": "trans",
 "amt": 1000
},{
  "id": "wf",
  "amt": 600,
  "min":  2000
},{
  "id": "inst",
  "amt": 2000,
  "error": "invalid"
}]
```

Comment: order by what id or amt or error ?? @Senthil

Comment: @UdalPal thanks for reply, have mentioned the conditions                              ``` `obj` with `no error key && amt > min` should display at the top in sorted manner by amt.
`obj` with `amt<min` should display next 
`obj` with `error` should display last```

Comment: why `sf` in second place `no error key && amt > min should display at the top in sorted manner by amt`?

Comment: @User863 yes...

Comment: What about `amt == min`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this function will do what you want. It is similar to yours but includes the extra checks on the `mins` and `valids`. It then sorts each array by `amt` ascending before concatenating them together:

```js
var obj =[{
 "id": "trans",
 "amt": 1000
},{
 "id": "fund",
 "amt": 500
},{
  "id": "inst",
  "amt": 2000,
  "error": "invalid"
},{
  "id": "wf",
  "amt": 600,
  "min":  2000
},{
  "id": "sf",
  "amt": 500,
  "min": "250"
}];

function sortObj(a, b) {
  return a.amt - b.amt;
}

function orderData(obj) {
   errors = obj.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty('error'));
   errors.sort(sortObj);
   mins   = obj.filter(e => !e.hasOwnProperty('error') && e.hasOwnProperty('min') && e.amt < e.min);
   mins.sort(sortObj);
   valids = obj.filter(e => !e.hasOwnProperty('error') && (!e.hasOwnProperty('min') || e.amt > e.min));
   valids.sort(sortObj);
   return valids.concat(mins).concat(errors);
}

console.log(orderData(obj));
```